# ReactJS animating removal/addition from array of components at the same time

Tags: reactjs, animation

I have several list components in a tree-like data structure and I want to animate them in a way that when I click on an item, its children slide in from the right and at the same time the previous list slides out to the left.

I used an array for this with `react-transition-group`, if I add items to it, it works, but if I try to remove one from it, it fails.

I have a demo here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/k1wyqo64lo

If I uncomment line 91 `path.shift()` it stops animating.
How can I make them animate at the same time?

Comment: you are using the the array index as the `key` for your items in the transition group, so react thinks it's the same element in that position. Try using something that more accurately identifies which item it is.

Comment: @shamsup Thank you very much. It worked like a charm! If you want to paste it into an answer I'd be glad to accept it.